# New to blender, why is my file so large

Tags: mesh, svg

first of all I'm new to blender, and I managed to import some SVG files I created of the basic layouts of the models I have.

Its a display video/monitor with its wall mount. Can anyone tell me why the file is large? Also how do I fuse the parts together so it moves as one. Not creating a group, but make it one object for the mount, and one object for the display.

Not sure if you got what I mean,

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hi. This question was put on hold because as it stands it is not answerable for lack of essential details to understand the issue. Remember only you have access to your scene, so unless you describe it thoroughly only you know your exact setup, settings and what steps you took to arrive where your are now. Please describe in detail what your issue is, possibly supported by [some accompanying screenshots](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) with the [edit] button above. Don't post a comment or ask a new question, editing will automatically put it up for review so it can be reopened.

Answer (score 1):

The .blend files store Blender's internal state which can result in big file sizes when there are plenty geometry, materials, packed textures and/or animations in the project. The more content is in your project, the larger the file.

In your instances it may be large because the imported SVGs use many points to describe paths or Bézier curves. Since Blender converts the SVG into curves in 3D space it also has to store another dimension compared to the 2D SVG.

The second question should be answered by existing answers on Blender's StackExchange:

- [Parenting objects](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26108/how-do-i-parent-objects)
- [Merging](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76700/merge-multiple-meshes-into-one-single-mesh)