# Merge Grid Lines into single Mesh

Tags: mesh, wireframe

I created this grid for use in a game. Users will use the grid as a guide to add road.

I created the mesh by drawing a rectangular plane and performing several arrays. Then I applied the "wireframe" modifier to create lines.

I now want to merge all the lines/planes together to create single mesh. How is this possible?

Ideally, I'm trying to reduce file size as I just need the lines visible.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge multiple meshes into one single mesh?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76700/merge-multiple-meshes-into-one-single-mesh)

Comment: Could just go Add > Mesh > Grid .. Wire Frame modifier... apply if you want...