# Merge multiple meshes into one hollow one for sculpting

Tags: mesh, sculpting

I hope there has not been answered this question since I have been looking for it for more than an hour.

My question is related to [this one](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76700/merge-multiple-meshes-into-one-single-mesh), but I could not make it work as I wanted it to.

I have this humanoid mesh made from joined copies of the same original sphere created on a new sculpting file. My intention is to use this as a base for sculpting.

[image]

The problem is that the vertices are not connected and at the moment of trying to add clay strips or simply draw, they never merge and gets all weird.

[image]

I was trying to remove all the vertices hidden inside to see if it helps the Merge by Distance option but was more work than expected and I suppose there should be something to achieve this.

By playing with the distance I was getting close to have it done, but at the end the vertices started jumping everywhere leaving it unuseful.

What should be the way to make it work?

Comment: I don't think you can merge anything with the sculpt tools, you probably need to go back to Edit mode, select tall and P > separate By Loose Parts, go back to Object mode and merge them with the Boolean modifier

Comment: Thank you @moonboots for your answer. I was not intending to merge them with the sculpting tools, I was not clear enough with that. I actually had a copy of the originals in Collection.bak so I did not need to separate them. I was able to get what I wanted from your suggestion with the boolean modifier. You should write a complete answer with that so I can accept it as the answer. The vertices do not end exactly as before, but they will be fixed with the sculpting anyway. Thank you again.