# How to make object from collection

Tags: objects, collections, instances

How I can transform objects in **collection** to single object?
I dont want still to use **select objects** in collection to move with all things inside.
Is there any simplier way?
I know about instances collection but this is not what I am looking for.
For example: I am very happy with my couch and I want to have single onject from used cubes.
Thank you very much
[image]

Comment: As in make into one mesh eg select bits &  Ctrl-J join?  Or perhaps https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76700/merge-multiple-meshes-into-one-single-mesh

Comment: Oh, Yes this is what I looked for. Thank you very much