# Texture Distortion when Separating Mesh

Tags: mesh, uv, edit-mode, texture-coordinates

when I separate a mesh (by Selection), I get a texture distortion as in the images below. Same happens when I use "Duplicate" or "Split"

Overall goal is to transfer an additional UV map onto parts of the mesh, Data Transfer Modifier doesn't yield great results in this matter so I need to separate the mesh to get the same topology...

Any way I can prevent the texture distortion? When I hide the selected polygons, more than the selection is hidden, so this might be the issue here

[image: Initial mesh]
[image: Separate by Selection]

Comment: Little update: After separating by selection, the total verts count will increase. The main mesh will have more verts after the separation that it should have had...

Comment: do you mean that the shading is changing if you separate one mesh in two separate meshes?

Comment: Shading must be it! UVs remain the exact same (checked it). But when I try "Shade Smooth", the distortion still exists... Any ideas on how to align the shading back to normal?

Comment: Another update: Faces are not connected! When I pull on any vertex, all four connected faces move along. When I pull the vertex on the seam (where both meshes have been joined), only 2 faces move along and create a crease (easy speaking: so that I can look inside the mesh)). This explains why I have more verts after joining, I have duplicate ones. How can I combine/link/merge them?

Comment: I' m not sure to understand, if you've split the edges, the shading won't work, but you can correct that with a Data Transfer modifier so that it gets the same shading as if the edges were not split

Answer (score 0):

Answer found in this thread: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/76707/152716

BoolTool won't work with Shapekeys, but Knife Tool works just fine. How to in Blender 3.2:

- Join the meshes with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>
- In *Edit Mode*, select all faces of the inferior object (the one previously separated from the main mesh)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and choose *Intersect (Knife)*
- Expand the little popup menu in the bottom left corner and change *Source* to *Self Intersect*

Works like a charm!